# Dynatrace API - Extract request count(success, 4xx, 5xx) for each service by service name

Tags: dynatrace

I am trying to extract the request count request count(success, 4xx, 5xx) for each web service under my project. I tried below query , but it is not giving what I am expected.

**builtin:service.requestCount.total** metric key

```
https://www.dynatrace.xx.com/e/12345-6539-4ea3-aab8-a9985ae713d4/api/v2/metrics/query?metricSelector=builtin:service.requestCount.total&entitySelector=type(SERVICE)&from=now-6h&resolution=3w&api-token=<token_name>
```

[image]

**builtin:service.keyRequest.total.count** metric key

```
https://www.dynatrace.xx.com/e/1234-6539-4ea3-aab8-a9985ae713d4/api/v2/metrics/query?metricSelector=builtin:service.keyRequest.total.count&entitySelector=type(SERVICE)&from=now-6h&resolution=3w&api-token=<token_name>
```

[image]

In multi dimensional analysis chart I could see the count correctly

[image]

Can someone help me with the API query, where I can pass the service name as parameter in request and get the request count associated with that service request.

**Edited :**
Please find below API response for the query

```
> {
>     "totalCount": 2,
>     "nextPageKey": null,
>     "resolution": "3m",
>     "result": [
>         {
>             "metricId": "builtin:service.requestCount.total:filter(and(in(\"dt.entity.service\",entitySelector(\"type(service),entityName(~\"ControllerName~\")\")))):splitBy(\"dt.entity.service\"):avg:auto:sort(value(avg,descending)):limit(100)",
>             "data": [
>                 {
>                     "dimensions": [
>                         "SERVICE-376AE4987839A1D7"
>                     ],
>                     "dimensionMap": {
>                         "dt.entity.service": "SERVICE-376AE4987839A1D7"
>                     },
>                     "timestamps": [
>                         1645673400000,
>                         1645673580000,
>                         1645673760000,
>                         1645673940000,
>                         1645674120000,
>                         1645674300000,
>                         1645674480000,
>                         1645674660000,
>                         1645674840000,
>                         1645675020000,
>                         1645675200000,
>                         1645675380000,
>                         1645675560000,
>                         1645675740000,
>                         1645675920000,
>                         1645676100000,
>                         1645676280000,
>                         1645676460000,
>                         1645676640000,
>                         1645676820000,
>                         1645677000000,
>                         1645677180000,
>                         1645677360000,
>                         1645677540000,
>                         1645677720000,
>                         1645677900000,
>                         1645678080000,
>                         1645678260000,
>                         1645678440000,
>                         1645678620000,
>                         1645678800000,
>                         1645678980000,
>                         1645679160000,
>                         1645679340000,
>                         1645679520000,
>                         1645679700000,
>                         1645679880000,
>                         1645680060000,
>                         1645680240000,
>                         1645680420000,
>                         1645680600000,
>                         1645680780000,
>                         1645680960000,
>                         1645681140000,
>                         1645681320000,
>                         1645681500000,
>                         1645681680000,
>                         1645681860000,
>                         1645682040000,
>                         1645682220000,
>                         1645682400000,
>                         1645682580000,
>                         1645682760000,
>                         1645682940000,
>                         1645683120000,
>                         1645683300000,
>                         1645683480000,
>                         1645683660000,
>                         1645683840000,
>                         1645684020000,
>                         1645684200000,
>                         1645684380000,
>                         1645684560000,
>                         1645684740000,
>                         1645684920000,
>                         1645685100000,
>                         1645685280000,
>                         1645685460000,
>                         1645685640000,
>                         1645685820000,
>                         1645686000000,
>                         1645686180000,
>                         1645686360000,
>                         1645686540000,
>                         1645686720000,
>                         1645686900000,
>                         1645687080000,
>                         1645687260000,
>                         1645687440000,
>                         1645687620000,
>                         1645687800000,
>                         1645687980000,
>                         1645688160000,
>                         1645688340000,
>                         1645688520000,
>                         1645688700000,
>                         1645688880000,
>                         1645689060000,
>                         1645689240000,
>                         1645689420000,
>                         1645689600000,
>                         1645689780000,
>                         1645689960000,
>                         1645690140000,
>                         1645690320000,
>                         1645690500000,
>                         1645690680000,
>                         1645690860000,
>                         1645691040000,
>                         1645691220000,
>                         1645691400000,
>                         1645691580000,
>                         1645691760000,
>                         1645691940000,
>                         1645692120000,
>                         1645692300000,
>                         1645692480000,
>                         1645692660000,
>                         1645692840000,
>                         1645693020000,
>                         1645693200000,
>                         1645693380000,
>                         1645693560000,
>                         1645693740000,
>                         1645693920000,
>                         1645694100000,
>                         1645694280000,
>                         1645694460000,
>                         1645694640000,
>                         1645694820000,
>                         1645695000000
>                     ],
>                     "values": [
>                         6,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         5,
>                         1,
>                         4,
>                         1,
>                         2,
>                         6,
>                         2,
>                         5,
>                         7,
>                         1,
>                         3,
>                         3,
>                         4,
>                         null,
>                         5,
>                         9,
>                         8,
>                         3,
>                         3,
>                         4,
>                         null,
>                         3,
>                         1,
>                         2,
>                         3,
>                         1,
>                         5,
>                         2,
>                         5,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         4,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         2,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         2,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         5,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         4,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         3,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         2,
>                         null,
>                         2,
>                         7,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         1,
>                         4,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         4,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         5,
>                         2,
>                         6,
>                         5,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         3,
>                         2,
>                         3,
>                         null
>                     ]
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "dimensions": [
>                         "SERVICE-BC7B97C170AF3FD6"
>                     ],
>                     "dimensionMap": {
>                         "dt.entity.service": "SERVICE-BC7B97C170AF3FD6"
>                     },
>                     "timestamps": [
>                         1645673400000,
>                         1645673580000,
>                         1645673760000,
>                         1645673940000,
>                         1645674120000,
>                         1645674300000,
>                         1645674480000,
>                         1645674660000,
>                         1645674840000,
>                         1645675020000,
>                         1645675200000,
>                         1645675380000,
>                         1645675560000,
>                         1645675740000,
>                         1645675920000,
>                         1645676100000,
>                         1645676280000,
>                         1645676460000,
>                         1645676640000,
>                         1645676820000,
>                         1645677000000,
>                         1645677180000,
>                         1645677360000,
>                         1645677540000,
>                         1645677720000,
>                         1645677900000,
>                         1645678080000,
>                         1645678260000,
>                         1645678440000,
>                         1645678620000,
>                         1645678800000,
>                         1645678980000,
>                         1645679160000,
>                         1645679340000,
>                         1645679520000,
>                         1645679700000,
>                         1645679880000,
>                         1645680060000,
>                         1645680240000,
>                         1645680420000,
>                         1645680600000,
>                         1645680780000,
>                         1645680960000,
>                         1645681140000,
>                         1645681320000,
>                         1645681500000,
>                         1645681680000,
>                         1645681860000,
>                         1645682040000,
>                         1645682220000,
>                         1645682400000,
>                         1645682580000,
>                         1645682760000,
>                         1645682940000,
>                         1645683120000,
>                         1645683300000,
>                         1645683480000,
>                         1645683660000,
>                         1645683840000,
>                         1645684020000,
>                         1645684200000,
>                         1645684380000,
>                         1645684560000,
>                         1645684740000,
>                         1645684920000,
>                         1645685100000,
>                         1645685280000,
>                         1645685460000,
>                         1645685640000,
>                         1645685820000,
>                         1645686000000,
>                         1645686180000,
>                         1645686360000,
>                         1645686540000,
>                         1645686720000,
>                         1645686900000,
>                         1645687080000,
>                         1645687260000,
>                         1645687440000,
>                         1645687620000,
>                         1645687800000,
>                         1645687980000,
>                         1645688160000,
>                         1645688340000,
>                         1645688520000,
>                         1645688700000,
>                         1645688880000,
>                         1645689060000,
>                         1645689240000,
>                         1645689420000,
>                         1645689600000,
>                         1645689780000,
>                         1645689960000,
>                         1645690140000,
>                         1645690320000,
>                         1645690500000,
>                         1645690680000,
>                         1645690860000,
>                         1645691040000,
>                         1645691220000,
>                         1645691400000,
>                         1645691580000,
>                         1645691760000,
>                         1645691940000,
>                         1645692120000,
>                         1645692300000,
>                         1645692480000,
>                         1645692660000,
>                         1645692840000,
>                         1645693020000,
>                         1645693200000,
>                         1645693380000,
>                         1645693560000,
>                         1645693740000,
>                         1645693920000,
>                         1645694100000,
>                         1645694280000,
>                         1645694460000,
>                         1645694640000,
>                         1645694820000,
>                         1645695000000
>                     ],
>                     "values": [
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         1,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null,
>                         null
>                     ]
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The metrics have a dimension `service`, i.e. you can filter by certain services via the `filter` on the service-name.

You can build, test and refine the query in the UI:

[image: Metric Query UI]

And then use the tab `Code` to see the metric-selector that you can also use in the REST API:

[image: Metric Selector]

Comment: Thanks @centic for your response, when I run the above query with my service(controller name which currently has 2 endpoint/services associated to it), I see a different response in postman, I finding it difficult in identifying the end point name as it is coming as 
"dimensions": [
                        "SERVICE-376AE4987839A1D7"
                    ]
Can you please help me if there is a way to find the exact name associated to above dimension(could be my endpoint name)

Comment: Also when I run the query to fetch count of last one hour only, I see an array of timestamps got printed along with an array of values, can you also please help me if there is a way to get only a single count of last one hour

Comment: As I could not add the postman response in comment, I have edited my question and add the response there, please check and help me out

Comment: Please look at the metric selector documentation, especially "sum" is interesting for you to sum up values across the timeframe. The SERVER-XXX is the intternal id. You can find it when you open the page for the Service in the UI and look at the URL, it should contain this id as one of the query parameters.

Comment: I am a newbie to dynatrace and api world, I want to retrieve the data related to builtin:service.errors.fivexx.rate not sure how to do it via postman - any help will be much appreciated - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you finally figured out, but

```
builtin:service.keyRequest.total.count
```

Yhe response of this is an array containing each point based on a timestamp, similar to a dynatrace chart. In order to get the total amount, you need to do some operations:

```
builtin:service.keyRequest.total.count:fold(sum)
```

Using `fold:(sum)`, one single value is responded (you are using an add operation).

Common data operations like median, average, máximum works as well—dynatrace call them aggregations; check the documentation.